# HLF Multiple Chaincodes vs. Multiple Smart Contracts

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am currently designing an application to be used to conduct transactions of an entity (e.g. a corporation).

1. When should the application have **multiple chaincodes**? In other words, what is the purpose of multiple chaincodes?
2. Why should a chaincode have **multiple smart contracts**? Should I have multiple smart contract for one that is used to submit transactions (e.g. making changes to world state) and another for evaluating transactions (e.g. querying from world state)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running a business, some organizations have to come into a consensus and so they have to create a **channel** where only permissioned organizational properties have access.

Here within a channel every valid organizational peer hold a physical copy of business transactional records which is known as **ledger** where the ledger is identical which means every ledger that belongs to same channel must hold the same records.

A ledger consists of two distinct, though related, parts – a **world state** and a **blockchain**. The world state – a database that holds current values of a set of ledger states. The blockchain – a transaction log that records all the changes that have resulted in the current the world state.

A **chaincode** is the business logic that is used to read the records of ledger or to write new records into the ledger or to update existing records.

A chaincode is consist with multiple **smart contracts**.

So The convention is for each channel, you need an identical chaincode. If you have 2 channel, than it's the convention that you have two different chaincodes.